# Unable to install Nvidia driver 510 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, drivers, nvidia

I try to install nvidia driver 510, and I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-510 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there anything I can try?

I have tried looking for held packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

And there is no output

Comment: I use RHEL 7 with nvidia, and the `libglvnd` has been problematic for me where I've had to `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.147.run --help` and use the option to force a `libglvnd` install or reinstall.  Sorry don't have linux on at the moment but using the nvidia .run and doing a verbose help peruse everything it spits out and look for what may be relevant in addition to `glvnd`.  hope that helps

Comment: Have you tried with `aptitude`? `aptitude` can offer a  number of different resolutions and also lets you explore the reasons behind the conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message on ubuntu 20 (trying to update from driver-470 to driver-510).

GAD3R's solution of adding the Canonical Kernel repo did not work for me, nor did the GUI driver update process.

Using [nvidia's run file](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx) directly did successfully install the 510 driver.

Note that I had to log out of the GUI to kill processes/applications using the GPU.

```
CTL + ALT + F1 (to go to a terminal only interface)
```

Then from either a ssh connection or after signing back in through the terminal only interface...

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

or

```
sudo stop gdm
```

and finally

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.47.03.run
```

and follow the prompt.

Even though my problem was solved, am still a linux noob and would like to know what other strategies might work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Canonical Kernel Team repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
```